# laravel 7.14 insert multiple rows/product in cart table using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to save multiple rows in cart table in database. I'm loading all products in a html table with a checkbox. A user will select as many product and add it in the cart. On form submission product_id will be saved from products table along with user_id and currency and price can be added later from and edit cart form. I haven't created foreign keys yet.

Heres' my HTML with foreach loop:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" class="" value="{{$product->id}}"></th>
            <td style="cursor: pointer;">
              <a href="{{ route('dashboard.product', $product->coil_id) }}" class="text-dark text-decoration-none">detail</a>
            </td>
            <td><p>{{ $product->coil_id }}</p></td>
            <td>
              <p>{{ $product->sub_family }}</p>
            </td>
            
          </tr>
          @endforeach
```

This my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // $request->merge([ 
    //     'product_id' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('product_id'))
    // ]);  

    $this->validate($request, [
        'product_id' => 'required',
        'currency' => '',
        'price' => '',
    ]);

    $product_id = implode(',', (array) $request->get('product_id'));


    $cart = new Cart;
    $cart->product()->sync($product_id);
    // $cart->product_id = $request->input('product_id');
    $cart->currency = $request->input('currency');
    $cart->price = $request->input('price');
    $cart->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    if($cart->save()) {
        $request->session()->flash('toast_success', 'Item(s) added in cart');
    }else{
        $request->session()->flash('toast_error', 'There was an error, Please try again');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Cart Model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
protected $fillable = [
    'product_id', 
    'currency',
    'price',
    'user_id',
];
```

My Products Controller:

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class);
}
```

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: I want to save multiple rows in cart table. I'm using Checkbox to select multiple product id.